# Responsive Canvas in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to do a responsive canvas. All my tests has been doing with a 600x600 canvas and with that height and width it works OK and paint every line correctly. The problem is that I have tried this:

```
 #myCanvas {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    min-height: 600px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Just for the record, myCanvas is inside a sm-col-8.

And it looks nice on my laptop and looks nice on my phone but (because of my draw() function, because it was thinking for a square) the draw starts more like in the down-left corner (nearby) and it should start at up-right corner.

So, I don't want to change my draw() function but what I'm looking for is to reescale the canvas size. I mean: If I'm in a laptop/tablet.. with 600x600, show it at that size, but if I'm on my phone which has 384x640 show it like 300x300? I don't know if it could be a good solution.

My draw function:

```
function drawLines(lines,i,table,xtotal,ytotal){

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    var xIni;
    var xFin;
    var yIni;
    var yFin;

    xIni = (c.width*parseInt(lines[i][1])/xtotal);
    yIni = (c.height*parseInt(lines[i][2])/ytotal);
    xFin = (c.width*parseInt(lines[i][3])/xtotal);
    yFin = (c.height*parseInt(lines[i][4])/ytotal);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(xIni,c.height-yIni);
    ctx.lineTo(xFin,c.height-yFin);
    ctx.lineWidth=4;

    ctx.strokeStyle = colorAleatorio();

    ctx.stroke();

}
```

Answer (score 5):

With Bootstrap, use:

```
<canvas id="canvas" class='img-responsive' style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make your html Canvas responsive by using the `context.scale` command.

The .scale command will scale the **internal coordinates system** used by canvas.

This means you do not need to change any of your own drawing coordinates because canvas will automatically transform your coordinates into scaled canvas coordinates for you.

```
// save the original width,height used in drawLines()
var origWidth=600;
var origHeight=600;
var scale=1.00;


// reference to canvas and context
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


// call this after resizing
// send in the new maximum width,height desired
function resizeAndRedraw(newMaxWidth,newMaxHeight){

    // calc the global scaling factor that fits into the new size
    // and also maintains the original aspect ratio
    scale=Math.min((newMaxWidth/origWidth),(newMaxHeight/origHeight))

    // resize the canvas while maintaining correct aspect ratio
    canvas.width=origWidth*scale;
    canvas.height=origHeight*scale;

    // Note: changing the canvas element's width or height will
    // erase the canvas so you must reissue all your drawing commands        
    drawLines(lines,i,table,xtotal,ytotal);

}


// call drawLines 
function drawLines(lines,i,table,xtotal,ytotal){

    // scale the canvas coordinate system to the current scale
    // Note: This scales the coordinates used internally
    // by canvas. It does not resize the canvas element
    ctx.scale(s,s);

    // now do your drawing commands
    // You do not need to adjust your drawing coordinates because
    // the Canvas will do that for you
    var xIni;
    var xFin;
    var yIni;
    var yFin;

    xIni = (c.width*parseInt(lines[i][1])/xtotal);
    yIni = (c.height*parseInt(lines[i][2])/ytotal);
    xFin = (c.width*parseInt(lines[i][3])/xtotal);
    yFin = (c.height*parseInt(lines[i][4])/ytotal);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(xIni,c.height-yIni);
    ctx.lineTo(xFin,c.height-yFin);
    ctx.lineWidth=4;

    ctx.strokeStyle = colorAleatorio();

    ctx.stroke();

    // restore the context to it's unscaled state
    ctx.scale(-s,-s);

}
```